# NG-ZORRO - override default style in library

Tags: angular, angular-library, ng-zorro-antd

I have an Angular library, packaged by ng-packagr, which wraps the `NzTableComponent`.
I need to provide a custom style, by overriding default ones, for example

```
@table-border-radius-base: 5px;
@table-header-bg: gray;
```

However, placing this in the component `.less` file

`table-custom.component.less`

```
@import 'ng-zorro-antd/table/style/index';
@import 'ng-zorro-antd/table/style/size';

@table-border-radius-base: 0;
@table-header-bg: black;
```

seems it isn't working.
Any idea?

Comment: did you imported them by @import ??

Comment: @FarukT sure, you can see it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-zorro-antd/table/style/size` that you import, itself imports `../../style/themes/index` and the variables you try to override are defined in the latter. It means that the new definitions of variables that you have made are ignored because they came after their use in the classes.

Here you don't have many options.
* Option 1 : You duplicate the library's less files and put the new values you wish within these duplicated files. The problems is that you won't take advantage of the library's evolution automatically.

- Option 2 : you keep your code as it is and in you less file you override only the classes that interest you (for example using ::ng-deep). As example, It would look like this:

```
@import 'ng-zorro-antd/table/style/index';
@import 'ng-zorro-antd/table/style/size';

@table-border-radius-base: 0;
@table-header-bg: black;

::ng-deep table {
 border-radius: @table-border-radius-base @table-border-radius-base 0 0; // the property will be overriden by the variables you have defined
}
...
```

Concerning the `::ng-deep`: the documentation says that it is deprecated even if it still largely used. To avoid this problem, if you have a general styles file that is not related only to a specific component, you can put the styles you want to override into this file without the `::ng-deep`.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the "if you have a general styles", is there a way to do so for a library? I've found hacks/custom scripts only.

Comment: You can always add a `my-lib-styles.less` file at the same level than `public_api.ts` file of you lib, but you have to make to sure to include it in the main using project's general style file. You have to do this, because, if I'm not mistaken, there is no way to integrate it during the project build using `angular.json` file

Comment: Yeah... that's what I've read everywhere, no automatic global style for libraries. If I copy it at the same level of `public-api.ts` are you sure it will always be built&copied to the `dist` folder?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do it using the CLI unless you are using Angular 8 that have introduced the [CLI builders](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-cli-builders-d012d4489f1b). An other solution is to write your own script (npm, gulp or other) that copies the file and append it to you `ng build my-library`. Here is [git repo](https://github.com/haythem-ouederni/ng-best-practices) where I tried to put some best Angular practices where you can find how I use the global styles (`projects/connection/src/lib/cnx-styles.scss`) file even if don't need to copy it to my `dist`.